# How to show list current filter in Resource list

Tags: reactjs, polaris, shopify-activemerchant

I'm using resource list control of polaris. I have add some filter conditions and my list displayed with correct data. 
But i don't see current list filter area where i can remove my conditions.
How to display it?
This is my filter declaretion,
 I wonder is it some problem with my appliedFilters variable.

```
 filterControl={
                    <ResourceList.FilterControl
                      resourceName={resourceName}
                      filters={availableFilters}
                      appliedFilters={appliedFilters}
                      onFiltersChange={this.handleFiltersChange}
                      searchValue={searchValue}
                      onSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}             
                    />
                  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need set again data for appliedFilters on onFiltersChange event to display current filter list.
i suggest you store this variable in local state of component as code bellow:

```
this.setState({ appliedFilters:appliedFilters});
```